# Why is the hostname declared invalid when creating a URI

Tags: java

Running this code with JDK 1.8:

```
try {
    System.out.println( new URI(null, null, "5-12-145-35_s-81", 443, null, null, null));
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

results in this error: `java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in hostname at index 13: //5-12-145-35_s-81:443`

Where does this error come from, considering all the hostname characters seem legit, according to [Types of URI characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters)?

---

If I use these URLs: `//5-12-145-35_s-81:443` or `/5-12-145-35_s-81:443` the error is gone.

---

From the comments, I understand that, according to [RFC-2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), the hostname cannot contain any underscore characters.

**The question that still holds is why a hostname starting with slash or double slash is allowed to contain underscores?**

Comment: @ernest_k The scheme is not given, it's null.

Comment: if you still want _ in url @fg78nc workaround will work for you. Don't use / because hostname will be invalid and will not create field

Comment: See [RFC-2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) section 3.2.2. A hostname in a URI can only be one or more groups of alphanumeric + `-`, separated by dots

Comment: @MarkRotteveel java.net.URI is not up to date with the latest specs

Comment: @fg78nc Although RFC-3986 relaxes it, it still mentions that _"A registered name intended for lookup in the DNS uses the syntax defined in Section 3.5 of [RFC1034] and Section 2.1 of [RFC1123]."_, and that is basically the syntax of RFC-2396 section 3.2.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Host name must match the following syntax:

> ```
> hostname      = domainlabel [ "." ] | 1*( domainlabel "." ) toplabel [ "." ]
> domainlabel   = alphanum | alphanum *( alphanum | "-" ) alphanum
> toplabel      = alpha | alpha *( alphanum | "-" ) alphanum
> ```

As you can see, only `.` and `-` are allowed, `_` is not.

---

You then say that `//5-12-145-35_s-81:443` is allowed, and it is, but not for *host name*.

To see how that pans out:

```
URI uriBadHost = URI.create("//5-12-145-35_s-81:443");
System.out.println("uri = " + uriBadHost);
System.out.println("  authority = " + uriBadHost.getAuthority());
System.out.println("  host = " + uriBadHost.getHost());
System.out.println("  port = " + uriBadHost.getPort());
```

```
URI uriGoodHost = URI.create("//example.com:443");
System.out.println("uri = " + uriGoodHost);
System.out.println("  authority = " + uriGoodHost.getAuthority());
System.out.println("  host = " + uriGoodHost.getHost());
System.out.println("  port = " + uriGoodHost.getPort());
```

*Output*

```
uri = //5-12-145-35_s-81:443
  authority = 5-12-145-35_s-81:443
  host = null
  port = -1
```

```
uri = //example.com:443
  authority = example.com:443
  host = example.com
  port = 443
```

As you can see, when the `authority` has a valid host name, the `host` and `port` are parsed, but when not valid, the `authority` is treated as freeform text, and not parsed any further.

---

**UPDATE**

From comment:

> `System.out.println( new URI(null, null, "/5-12-145-35_s-81", 443, null, null, null))` outputs: ///5-12-145-35_s-81:443. I'm giving it as hostname

The `URI` constructor you're calling is a convenience method, and it simple builds a full URI string and then parses that.

Passing `"5-12-145-35_s-81", 443` becomes `//5-12-145-35_s-81:443`.
Passing `"/5-12-145-35_s-81", 443` becomes `///5-12-145-35_s-81:443`.

In the first, it's a *host* and *port*, and fails to parse.
In the second the *authority* part is empty, and `/5-12-145-35_s-81:443` is a *path*.

```
URI uri1 = new URI(null, null, "/5-12-145-35_s-81", 443, null, null, null);
System.out.println("uri = " + uri1);
System.out.println("  authority = " + uri1.getAuthority());
System.out.println("  host = " + uri1.getHost());
System.out.println("  port = " + uri1.getPort());
System.out.println("  path = " + uri1.getPath());
```

*Output*

```
uri = ///5-12-145-35_s-81:443
  authority = null
  host = null
  port = -1
  path = /5-12-145-35_s-81:443
```

Comment: Now I understand, but why, let's say `/a_b`, is allowed. The only difference is that this one is absolute, not relative

Comment: `System.out.println( new URI(null, null, "/5-12-145-35_s-81", 443, null, null, null))` outputs: `///5-12-145-35_s-81:443`. I'm giving it as hostname.

Comment: This behavior (when hostname is absolute) is strange, to say the least. The URI's constructor is giving a hostname and a port, and the resulted URI has neither one, only a path.

Answer (score 5):

Underscores are not supported in URIs.

> While a hostname may not contain other characters, such as the
>   underscore character (_), other DNS names may contain the
>   underscore.[5][6] This restriction was lifted by RFC 2181, Section 11.
>   Systems such as DomainKeys and service records use the underscore as a
>   means to assure that their special character is not confused with
>   hostnames. For example, _http._sctp.www.example.com specifies a
>   service pointer for an SCTP-capable webserver host (www) in the domain
>   example.com. Notwithstanding the standard, Chrome, Firefox, Internet
>   Explorer, Edge and Safari allow underscores in hostnames, although
>   cookies in IE do not work correctly if any part of the hostname
>   contains an underscore character

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_hostnames)

From Javadocs :

> public URI(String str) throws URISyntaxException Throws:
>   URISyntaxException - If the given string violates RFC 2396, as
>   augmented by the above deviations

[Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI-java.lang.String-)

(Hacky) Solution :

```
    URI url = URI.create("https://5-12-145-35_s-8:8080");

    System.out.println(url.getHost()) // null

    if (url.getHost() == null) {
        final Field hostField = URI.class.getDeclaredField("host");
        hostField.setAccessible(true);
        hostField.set(url, "5-12-145-35_s-81");
    }
    System.out.println(url.getHost()); // 5-12-145-35_s-81
```

This was reported as  - [JDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8019345)

Comment: Wow, that is a hacky solution. You may state that this may break in the future, as it is assuming internals about an internal class and uses reflection to access it directly. So the implementation might change with any Java release, in which case this could break. +1 for providing _a solution_ though.

Comment: As much I wanted to put this workaround I didn't, the problem with these things is just what Zabuza mention. + If we start to obey rules everything will start slowly to collapse. There is a good reason why this not work in first place.

Comment: "Systems such as DomainKeys and service records use the underscore as a means to assure that their special character is not confused with hostnames."  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) and there is good answer here [quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-underscores-not-allowed-in-DNS-host-names)

Comment: While a hostname may not contain other characters, such as the underscore character (_), other DNS names may contain the underscore

Comment: If you do that you will get `null` as host.

Answer (score 4):

The bug is not in Java but in naming the host, since an underscore is not a valid character in a hostname. Although widely used incorrectly, Java refuses to handle such hostnames

Comment: This one `/5-12-145-35_s-81:443` is legal.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem and got around it by identifying the host by it's address instead of it's name.

```java
InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
// detectedHostName = inetAddress.getHostName(); // returns 5-12-145-35_s-8
detectedHostName = inetAddress.getHostAddress(); // returns x.x.x.x
```

The result of `getHostAddress` can be safely passed to `URI` parser.

---

*I understand that this might not be a valid alternative for every case.*