# How do I find a service registered with Eureka knowing its name – without tinkering with DiscoveryService?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

How do I find a service registered with Eureka knowing its name? I was under the impression that once you include the `@LoadBalanced` annotation, the mapping is done behind the scenes for you, and all you need to do is to include the app's name.

**Somewhere in a requesting microservice**:

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced // note this
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        return restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PlanetService {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    public Planet getPlanet(String name) {
        return restTemplate.getForObject("http://planet_ms/api/planets?name=" + name, Planet.class);
    }
}
```

**Somewhere in a responding microservice**:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PlanetController {
    private final PlanetService planetService;
    @GetMapping("/planets")
    public Planet getPlanet(@RequestParam String name) {
        return planetService.getPlanet(name);
    }
}
```

```java
server.port=8081
spring.application.name=planet_ms
```

Apparently, it's not the case (however, it seemed to me it's what happened in [this video](https://youtu.be/4tSyz_v9w7Q?si=fQslD_DqcuMPuOKy&t=4232))

How do I ensure that a microservice name is successfully mapped to a host-port pair using `@LoadBalanced`? Do I really have to deal with a `DiscoveryClient`? If I decide to complicate my code and retrieve the host and the port directly, it works, but the idea of relying on that nice implicit mapping (and not doing anything manually) is so appealing. Surely, I can write a simple utility class and write the code just once (it's what I did indeed), but still, **why didn't `@LoadBalanced` work**?

```java
// if I do something like this, it works

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PlanetService {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private final DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;
    public Planet getPlanet(String name) {
        var planetMicroservice = discoveryClient.getInstances("planet_ms").get(0);
        String host = planetMicroservice.getHost();
        int port = planetMicroservice.getPort();
        return restTemplate.getForObject(format("http://%s:%d/api/planets?name=%s", host, port, name), Planet.class);
    }
}
```

**UPD:** I followed Ken Chan's advice and:

1. replaced underscores with hyphens

```
# example
spring.application.name=planet-ms
```

2. included a `loadbalancer` starter

```xml
<!-- pom -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

3. included `@LoadBalanced` annotations at the `@Bean` method *and* before a respective constructor parameter

```java
    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        return restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }
```

```java
    public PlanetService(@LoadBalanced RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public Planet getPlanet(String name) {
        return restTemplate.getForObject("http://planet-ms/api/planets?name=" + name,
                Planet.class);
    }
```

Result:

```
WARN 15492 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.c.l.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer      : No servers available for service: host.docker.internal
```

I have no idea what Docker has to do with it. I didn't use it for this application. Microservices are running:

[image]

Comment: A longer version is hopefully available [here](https://peerpad.net/#/w/markdown/8gtbbXHNCdWLeVYTDAFjHpnycsAm335iK3roTWi9tYeU/4XTTMD5ytzCKTdy4qA6h2xsN5UzX1wLSANhbVvqN5XMHUZFH6-K3TgUKMVxEfazKECFs2ZriKr9U8vDdyJxHbs4sGghxHnnH3gEe3JqYbhMUYXWqSpHPEUzLLfFQkEQbifDLudZ5MRR8w1hAp73fwvP37BCz7aoqrEToySBm4Wk6vF6EohMjBdyes6) (I was unsure whether providing all the details would violate the MRE rule)

Comment: Hello @JoreJoh, this should work. Looking at the log from `RoundRobinLoadBalancer`, it seems your app might be trying to resolve the host from serviceId twice instead of once only while processing the call, but we'd need to take a look at a sample project to verify. Please feel free to create a GH issue in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons and we will look at it, but might take some time to get to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally discovered a fix to the problem. Let me group things into ones that don't matter and the ones that do

#### Things that don't matter

1. Putting a `@LoadBalanced` annotation on a field/parameter of type `RestTemplate` if you only have one bean of that type (like I did)

```java
    public PlanetService(/* you don't need @LoadBalanced here, but you can put it if you want */ RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }
```

2. Having an explicit `loadbalancer` dependency (Eureka got it covered, look at the Compile Dependencies section [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client/4.0.3))

```xml
<!-- you don't need it -->

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>4.0.4</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
```

#### Things that do matter

1. Avoiding low dashes. I was under the impression that URI standards don't apply to application names since they should be replaced with valid host-port pairs anyway, but no. `planet-ms` is fine, `planet_ms` is not

```
{
  "error_message": "Request URI does not contain a valid hostname: http://planet_ms/api/planets?name=hoth"
}
```

2. *(it's the fix I was referring to at the beginning!)* Choosing a method of making requests to your microservices and sticking with it. See, I used the `@LoadBalanced` annotation to communicate with one microservice (`planet-ms`) and `DiscoveryClient` to communicate with another one (`converter-ms`). Like so:

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WeightService {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private final MicroserviceUtil mu;
    public Double getWeightInKilos(String weight) {
        String[] weightAndUnit = weight.split("(?<=\\d)(?=[a-z]+)");
        Double value = Double.valueOf(weightAndUnit[0]);
        String unit = weightAndUnit[1];
        if (unit.equals(WeightUnit.KILOS.toString())) {
            return value;
        } else if (unit.equals(WeightUnit.POUNDS.toString())) {
            return restTemplate.getForObject(String.format("http://%s/api/kilos?pounds=%s",
                    mu.getHostAndPort("converter-ms"), value), Double.class);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported unit");
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MicroserviceUtil {
    private final DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;
    public String getHostAndPort(String microserviceName) {
        var converterMicroservice = discoveryClient.getInstances(microserviceName).get(0); // no balancing needed since I have only one instance per microservice
        return converterMicroservice.getHost() + ":" + converterMicroservice.getPort();
    }
}
```

It led to this:

```
WARN 2580 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.c.l.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer      : No servers available for service: host.docker.internal
```

If I replace this

```java
            return restTemplate.getForObject(String.format("http://%s/api/kilos?pounds=%s",
                    mu.getHostAndPort("converter-ms"), value), Double.class);
```

with this

```java
            return restTemplate.getForObject("http://converter-ms/api/kilos?pounds=" + value,
                    Double.class);
```

everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

You are right. `@LoadBalanced` should integrate with `DiscoveryClient` behind the scene such that you do not need to deal with it.

Behind the scene `LoadBalancerAutoConfiguration` will process the `@LoadBalanced` annotated `RestTemplate` to setup such integration. But it will only enabled if there are any `LoadBalancerClient` implementation in the class-path. So guess that you forget to add any load-balancer implementation to the class-path ?

You should add `spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer` to your project , quoted from [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#rest-template-loadbalancer-client) as follows :

> Important : To use a load-balanced RestTemplate, you need to have a load-balancer implementation in your classpath. Add Spring Cloud LoadBalancer starter to your project in order to use it.

Another reason is if you define multiple `RestTemplate` beans , you have to use the `@LoadBalanced` which is also a `@Qualifier` to inject the one with the load balancing feature :

```java
@Service
public class PlanetService {

    @Autowired
    @LoadBalanced
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

}
```

And one more reason is hostname does not allow underscores.(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60239197/339637)). So you should change the name of the service that you call  (i.e `planet_ms`) to another name without underscores.

Comment: Thank you. But simply adding the starter didn't help, the URI doesn't get resolved. Do I need to manually add some bean to the context?

Comment: should be no need. also make sure you do not configure `spring.cloud.loadbalancer.enabled=false`

Comment: I don't........

Comment: Does this line smell fishy to you? To me it doesn't `restTemplate.getForObject("http://planet_ms/api/planets?name=" + name, Planet.class)` (`planet_ms` is a 100% valid service ID specified by `spring.application.name`, it is successfully registered with Eureka)

Comment: do you define multiple` RestTemplate` bean ? If yes , see my updated answer and try it .

Comment: Nope, I don't... It's my entire config: `@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example.weightonplanetmicroservice")
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        return restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }
}`

Comment: do you try it even you do not have ?

Comment: I removed the annotation if that's what you mean. I had it in place when I tested it

Comment: i am saying adding   `@LoadBalanced` when you autowired  `RestTemplate` into `PlanetService`. I never tell you to remove it....

Comment: Do you mean I should annotate both the `@Bean` method (which I did) and the field (which I didn't)?

Comment: yes. please see my updated answer for what i mean.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. I annotated a respective autowired constructor parameter with `@LoadBalanced`. The `loadbalancer` library is present in the classpath. The error is the same: `Request URI does not contain a valid hostname: http://planet_ms/api/planets?name=bespin`

Comment: then it is because hostname does not allow underscore , please see my updated answer. Try to change the the service name that you call from `planet_ms` to another name that is without underscore

Comment: I'm sorry to inform you but it didn't help either. The error message changed though. Please see the edit

Comment: I fixed it! See my answer if you're curious